# Python statsmodels and multivariate auto regressive models

Tags: statsmodels

I was wondering if statsmodels has the capability of dealing with multivariate autoregressive models.  Not VAR but models where the current value of the target variable is dependent upon its lagged values and the lagged values of other variables that may contribute to forecast accuracy

Comment: Do you really mean multivariate, with several dependent variables, or just one dependent (target) variable. If it's just one, then you can use OLS, if the error term is not serially correlated. If there are several dependent variables, then your requirement sounds like what VAR is doing.

Comment: YEs you are right.  I did more research and it looks like I need a VAR model where I am only interested in one element of the vector